# Lost option in dual boot menu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dualboot

I have dual boot on my machine: Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 11.
I do not use the Grub menu to choose the OS. Instead, I use the startup menu.
It have been working few weeks but now (I guess after some updates in Ubuntu), the Windows option disappeared from the boot menu.

When I run the following command in Ubuntu:

```
sudo ls -1 /boot/efi/EFI
```

I get the following output:

```
BOOT
HP
Microsoft
ubuntu
```

Is it possible to recover the Windows booting option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to boot to a Windows 11 installer usb stick or DVD and choose the recovery option. Try the automated startup fix, if it does not help, try going to the command prompt and use `bcdedit.exe` to edit the boot entries. It might be present on the EFI partition, so you must mount it first through `diskpart`.

`diskpart`

`list disk`

`select disk X` (change X for your device index shown above)

`list part` (shows the partitions of disk X, pick the one with about 100MB)

`assign letter=K` (choose whatever letter you want)

Now you should `exit` and then navigate to the EFI partition by typing `K:` and then `cd Boot` to navigate to where should be the BCD file, which contains the boot entries of the Windows Bootloader.

After you're at the exact location of the BCD file you can use the `bcdedit` command to add the entry to the file. There are plenty of guides on how to do this on the internet and you will absolutely find what you need by searching "how to add X boot entry to windows bootloader". Wish you the best.

Comment: The recovery option in Windows installer worked in my case.